# Updating images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have a problem with drawing images. What I need to do is change the source of an image by changing a variable like this:

```
    var playerImage = new Image();
    var imageName = "image.png";
    playerImage.src = imageName;
```

Then, I change the value of imageName on another place in the code. However, this does not work. The value of imageName actually changes but the image itself stays the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO - It seems that you did not visit the [help] to see how to ask questions. Hint: Show some more code and perhaps console error messages

Comment: When you change the variable imageName, it does not update the src. You need to update the source directly.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the value of `imageName` won't reload the image.

Re-appending the new value to the `playerImage.src` will reload it 

<s>(need to check if this works in all browsers tho)</s>.
Supported since IE3.02 (thanks to @mplungjan)

```
playerImage.src = "new/path/to/img";
```

Comment: It should work in all JS enabled browsers since IE3.02

Comment: You many need to add a cache buster if you load the same image - like `playerImage.src = "someanimation.gif?rnd="+new Date().getTime();` - and IE3.0 did NOT support images in JS - hence the old `if (document.images)` to handle browsers older than 3.02:)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the imageName won't do the trick; if you want to change the actual image, you need to assign a new value to playerImage.src